# unclear to parameters pass in promise model

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I confuse to How promise model work in AngularJS. The example below is the tutorial code that I find from github. I can confuse where the parameter "response" in then() comes from and how it works? Can anyone explain to me,please!

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

    RegisterController.$inject = ['UserService', '$location', '$rootScope'];
    function RegisterController(UserService, $location, $rootScope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.register = register;

        function register() {
            vm.dataLoading = true;
            UserService.Create(vm.user)
                .then(function (response) { // where response comes from?
                    if (response.success) {
                        // FlashService.Success('Registration successful', true);
                        console.log('Registration successful')
                        $location.path('/login');
                    } else {
                        // FlashService.Error(response.message);
                        console.log(response.message);
                        console.log('get error when register users')
                        vm.dataLoading = false;
                    }
                });
        }
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It called Promise - which replace the good old callback style for async methods. instead of passing a callback to UserService.Create, UserService.Create returns a promise which you can decide what comes after it (once it has been resolved or rejected). promise have the method then() which accepts 2 arguments:

1. function for handling resolved promise
2. function for handling rejected promise

It simplifies your flow + break the callback pyramid in cases of multiple callbacks.

Angular uses library called q:
https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: @ Thanks for answer my question! However, I still confuse to the parameter "response" in then(function(response). Does it pass from the outside of this controller?

Comment: Yea, this argument is coming from the function who resolved the Promise. 
In your case in is the returned value from UserService.Create